# User input a word then print letters of the word on a new line for java

Tags: java, string, while-loop, substring, indexof

I need help using just String method, indexOf, substring, accumulators, while loops. I want the user to input a word using JOptionPane.showInputDialog and will display each letter of word on a new line in the output. How do you do this in java?

Ex.

Input: `Dog`

Output:

```
D
o
g
```

Here's my code so far (it really needs correcting):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Exercise_28 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        String letters;
        int num1;
        int num2;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word: ");
        num1 = input.length() - 1;
        num2 = input.length() - num1 - 1;
        letters = input.substring(0, 1);

        while (num2 <= num1) {
            System.out.println(letters);
            num2++;
            letters = input.substring(num2, num2 + 1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question. And please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like that

```
 import javax.swing.*;
public class Exercise_28 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        String letters;
        int num1;
        int num2;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word: ");
        num1 = input.length() - 1;
        num2 = input.length() - num1 - 1;
           //  letters = input.substring(0, 1);

    while (num2 <= num1) {
        letters = input.substring(num2, num2 + 1);
        System.out.println(letters);
        num2++;
    }
    System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

error occurs when you want substring input without checking your num2 with while

Answer (score 0):

**The code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Exercise28 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word: ");
        
        //Solution1. input as array using chatAt(index)
        System.out.println("SOLUTION 1");
        int i =0;
        while(i< input.codePoints().count())
        {
            System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }

        //Solution2. Get a substring beginning at index and take 1 character. Remember endIndex is exclusive. Example substring(3, 4) take character at index = 3 to index = 4(exclusive), total 1 character,
        System.out.println("SOLUTION 2");
        i=0;
        while(i< input.length())
        {
            System.out.println(input.substring(i, i+1));
            i++;
        }

        //Solution3. Works correctly.
        System.out.println("SOLUTION 3");
        input.codePoints().forEach((int codePoint)-> {
            System.out.println(Character.toString(codePoint));
        });

    }
}
```

Solution1 and 2 works for characters less than Character.MAX_VALUE (65535), if you input is Unicode chars with surrogate pairs the output may be wrong.

Example.

**Input:** Dog
The output is OK for all solutions.

```
SOLUTION 1
D
o
g
SOLUTION 2
D
o
g
SOLUTION 3
D
o
g
```

**Input:** AA
The output is wrong for Solution 1 and 2, but ok for Solution3.

```
SOLUTION 1
A
?
?
SOLUTION 2
A
?
?
A
SOLUTION 3
A

A
```

---

**Output**

[image: output]

**With input**: HelloWorld
[image: input dialog]

```
SOLUTION 1
?
?
?
?
H
e
l
l
o
W
o
r
l
d
?
SOLUTION 2
?
?
?
?
H
e
l
l
o
W
o
r
l
d
?
?
?
?
?
?
SOLUTION 3


H
e
l
l
o
W
o
r
l
d
```

[image]